# React Native:How to get the date of the calendar view

Tags: react-native, events, calendar, react-native-calendars

I am using React-native-calendar to show the date of the existing booking. I am looking how to get the date of the month after going to previous month of the calendar

https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

i can see they specify at the top a calendar object but how i can access it, in react native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`onMonthChange`](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#basic-parameters) event to get the current visible month of the calendar.

```
// Handler which gets executed when visible month changes in calendar. Default = undefined
  onMonthChange={(month) => {console.log('month changed', month)}}
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I just tried. didn't realize it was not month, is the calendar object itself.